# Routing read-only queries to a read-only replica without modifying application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

RDS provides both read-only and read-write endpoints for database clusters; it can be beneficial to send read-only queries to read-only endpoint so that they can be routed to read replicas, potentially lowering the load on the primary node.

Unfortunately, the applications I'm using RDS with don't have separate database connections for read-only and read-write queries. Is there a way to (through a proxy, or otherwise) route the read-only queries (SELECT, etc) to the read-only endpoint, and the rest to the read-write endpoint?